# Fastest way to check whether the triangle inequality is satisfied

Tags: triangles

If we are given the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, and we simply add the 2 smallest sides and check to see if the sum is larger than the third side, will this *always* yield the correct answer i.e. will it always tell us if the triangle is a viable one? Thanks.

Comment: Yes.I think this is proved in geometry: any three positive real  numbers in which the sum of any two is greater than the third one are the sides of a triangle that is constructible.

Comment: Actually, I think its the easiest way to construct a triangle: Given three lengths $a,b,c$ first draw a chord of length $a$, at the first endpoint draw a circle of radius $b$ and at the second endpoint a circle of radius $c$. These two circles must intersect, because the distance of their centers $O_1O_2=a$ is less than the sum of radii $b+c$. Let $X$ be a point of intersection, then the triangle $\triangle O_1O_2X$ has side lengths $a,b,c$.